# Read start and end frame from baked animation in FBX when importing into Blender

Tags: python, animation, blender, fbx

I am doing some scripting with Blender as a module and having trouble retaining some information from an exported fbx. When the fbx was exported from another program, during the exportation process a start and end frame was selected for the baked animation. Is there anyway to regain this information when the model is imported into blender via python scripting?

Below is an example of the start and end frame setting when exporting the fbx from Maya:

[image]

This fbx file may have keyframes at other positions outside the specified start and end frame. These extra frames are picked up in Blender so it is unclear what frames are intended for use with the given fbx animation file.